# Trace32 Function RunTime does not work as expected

Tags: runtime, trace32

I'm trying to debug the execution flow of a piece of code from a point *A* to function call *B*.

For that purpose I'm activating some Trace graphics using a cmm script

```
SYStem.RESetTarget
Break.Delete
Break EcuM_Prv_StartOS
Go
WAIT !STATE.RUN() 5.s
Trace.Init
Trace.METHOD SNOOPer
Trace.Mode PC
Trace.Arm
Break  RE_CS_S_SquibDrv_Reset_func
Go
WAIT !STATE.RUN() 5.s
Trace.CHART.FUNC
```

What I expected in the Chart graph was to see all the function calls and time spent for any function from A (*EcuM_Prv_StartOS*) to B (*RE_CS_S_SquibDrv_Reset_func*).
But instead I only see some functions in between, As I probe if which functions has been executed I attach also in the graph the window with the stackframe that effectively shows all the calls until my breakpoint in B
[image]

So I wonder whether I'm doing something wrong or simply this graph does not work as I expected, meaning showing all the execution flow of the code.

Note: The uC is a Infineon tricore TC27X ; and this core actually does not have internal TRACE capabilities. But this functionality is under the *Perf TAB* not the *TRace TAB* and the Powerview GUI is not blocking the use of these charts so I guess is usable unlike other TRACE functionalities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have selected `Trace.METHOD SNOOPer`. That method means that some items (in your case the PC) are periodically sampled. That is not the suitable trace method for complex run-time analysis.

For a complex run-time analysis you need to use one of the following:

- Trace.METHOD **Anayzer** (requires a PowerTrace and a CPU supporting offchip-trace (parallel or serial))
- Trace.METHOD **CAnalyzer** (requires a CombiProbe and a CPU supporting offchip-trace via a tiny 4-bit trace port)
- Trace.METHOD **Onchip** (requires a CPU supporting onchip-trace)

Since you write that your core has internal trace capabilities (so you do have probably a so called "TriCore Emulation Device") I think `Trace.METHOD Onchip` is what you need.

For timing measurements with an onchip trace you have to ensure that your core's onchip trace actually provides some timing information with the program flow information. For a TriCore check TimeSTamp and TImeMode in the MCDS window.

---

For using samples of the program counter to getting just a rough clue in which part of your target software is executed the most, I recommend the `PERF` command group, which is very similar to the SNOOPer.

For measuring the time between A and B where the core stops in both A and B the `RunTime` command might also help.

Comment: Thanks Holger, unfortunately the CPU in my Production Board is not an Emulation Device so it does not support such 3 TRace Methods, only ART, LOGGER, Snooper FDX and La are available for selection.
Anyway I could debug something more using the TRace->Chart->Symbols graph, I setup a snooper + stack + PC . At least this time I saw much many functions executed in between and I could blame some buch of them that were causing a big delay.
BTW I've used the Runtime feature other times, but this time a needed a clue about timings ocurring from A to B not only the total spent time.

Comment: BTW, where do you got so much detailed information about the topic, I tried to follow the lauterbach documents about trace feature but I don't see clearly explained the huge number of options.